# Creating a test database for integration tests with Azure and Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure

I am setting up my ALM with `Azure` and `Visual Studio Online`.

One of the steps in my pipeline is to run integration tests, for which I typically re-create the test database (dropping if already exists) and populate it with the minimal data to perform my integration tests.

For this purpose, I plan to create a new database in Azure (myproject-test). But this will affect my billing, although not dramatically. My question is - do I have any other alternatives to creating a test database in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up somewhere!

You can use a VM and run SQL express on it. This would be a lot cheaper than SQL Azure as it would only cost the price of the VM.

Each build you can deploy your database to that server.